# cPanel cronjob doesn't run but works normally

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a cronjob setup on cPanel which doesn't seems to run, but it does when called directly.

Since I update some values in the database, I need to include the config file. So this is the start of the cron.php file:

```
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../main.php');
```

main.php is located at a folder called 'dev', while cron.php is located in a folder called 'cron' inside 'dev' (so it's dev/cron/cron.php).

Cronjob command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /var/home/username/public_html/dev/cron/cron.php
```

I've also tried curl method but got same result.

Comment: You've got everything using full paths, and not doing so is one of the most likely issues, so I'd say then that the most likely second issue is permissions -- the user running the cron doesn't have read permission into the homedir of the user where the script is. Check the cron log and/or the local mail account of the user running the cron for the error output.

Comment: Yeah you were right. Seems an include problem. Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/home/user/public_html/dev/main.php

Comment: How to fix?....

Comment: Nvm fixed!.....